# Como retornar POST na mesma div em que ela é executada AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Na verdade esta acontecendo 2 problemas:
1º tenho uma DIV CONTEUDO onde abro via AJAX o conteudo nela, o mesmo esta acontecendo tipo, se eu clicar 2 vez no mesmo link ele ao inves de recarregar a pagina ele esta simplesmente adicionando o conteudo novamente ficando 2 conteudo iguais em sequencia

2º essa mesma pagina que eu carrego possui um formulario de submit preciso que quando clicar em enviar ele fazer o servico na mesma DIV CONTEUDO que ele ja foi aberto.

Segue abaixo a parte do codigo

formulario de envio gerado pelo php

```
 echo "<form action=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\" method=\"post\"enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\n
Arquivo JPG:<br>
<input type=\"file\" name=\"vImage\" />\n
<input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn_enviar\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Enviar\" />";
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn_receber").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                   //pegando a url apartir do href do link
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        type: 'GET',
        context: jQuery('#conteudo'),
        success: function(data){
            this.append(data);
        }
    });     
});

$(".btn_enviar").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                   //pegando a url apartir da action do form
        url: $(this).parent("form").attr("action"),
        data: 'busca=' +$("#busca").val(),
        type: 'POST',
        context: jQuery('#conteudo'),
        success: function(data){
            this.append(data);
        }
       });     
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Bem não entendi 100% da sua pergunta, vou tentar quebrar em parte, vamos lá ...

1- Vc tem 1 DIV que ao clicar num link qualquer carrega um formulário dentro dessa DIV, porém se clicar no link que carrega esse formulário ele carrega o formulário de novo;

2- Você quer que após aberto o formulário dentro dessa DIV quando a pessoa envie ele carrega dentro dessa própria DIV;

Bem se foi isso que entendi vou tentar dizer o que esta errado na sua lógica ...

1- O problema de clicar no link e ele carregar 2x é porque esta usado o método ["append"](http://api.jquery.com/append/) do JQyery, esse método faz com que o conteúdo que você defini-o seja colocado ao final do elemento, no caso ele coloca sua chamada Ajax ao final do DIV quantas vezes clicar, assim sendo recomendo que troque pelo método ["html"](http://api.jquery.com/html/), onde o comportamento normal dele é limpar o conteúdo do elemento e recolocar.

```
this.append(data); <=> Trocar <=> this.html(data);
```

2- Já o segundo problema È que você terá que criar uma nova chamada Ajax completa para esse formulário filtrando os dados e tals dentro dessa chama, pois do jeito que esta hoje ele está enviando para a URL do "action" que tem prioridade sobre os outros eventos e também o "enctype" está perdendo nesse processo e como efeito seu UPLOAD de imagem não vai funcionar ... u rascunho do que deve ser feito seria:

```
<form id="form">
<!-- Seu formulário -->
<input type="button" class="btn_enviar" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>

$(".btn_enviar").click(function(event) {
 //Execura as ações de leitura do formulário aqui, isoladamente
}
```

Não sei se ficou claro ...

Comment: quanto ao 1  foi resolvido, o segundo estou tenando fazer mais ta dificil